# Javascript get coordinate of highlight text

Tags: javascript, range, selection

I would like to get the position of highlighted text but not the bounded yellow rect (using `range.getBoundingClientRect()`) here I'm talking about the red area in the picture meaning it have an indent. Basically I want to save selection area and be-able to replicate them. I could not use the technique to save and restore Range object.

[image]

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
function addMarkerOnSelection(){
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
  var scrolltop = jQuery('body,html').scrollTop();
  //var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  var marker = document.createElement('div');
  marker.style.position = 'absolute';
  marker.style.display='block';
  marker.style.left = rect.left + 'px';
  marker.style.top = scrolltop + rect.top + 'px';
  marker.style.height = rect.bottom-rect.top + 'px';
  marker.style.width = rect.right-rect.left + 'px';
  marker.style.border='1px solid black';
  marker.style.background='yellow';
  marker.style.opacity = 0.5;
  document.body.appendChild(marker);
}
```

You can try google docs, try no highlight multiple line of text and add an comment. They wrap the highlight area correctly.

I have another approach, using `Range.surroundContents` I am able to wrap content with an element and its work as expected. BUT how to save it without saving the whole text content?

```
function surround(){
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var marker = document.createElement('span');
  marker.style.border='1px solid black';
  marker.style.background='yellow';
  marker.style.opacity = 0.5;
  range.surroundContents(marker);
};
```

[image]

Comment: [rangy](https://github.com/timdown/rangy) may help. it have `saveRanges` and `restoreRanges`

Comment: Rangy would put a start marker and end marker into a text and would require me to save the text as well. I dont want to alter that :-?